# PMCalender Moving lable down when shaking ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, shake

when i rotate in simulator to Right or left and Shaking ipad this happens 
[image]

an solution regarding this ??

Answer (score 0):

Used this Calender updated version  `https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar` and it got fixed